# Where am I going wrong while trying to solve for $m$ in this quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $m$ so that the entire graph of the following function would be above the $x$ axis:

$$y=mx^{ 2 }+(m+7)x+m+15$$

Steps I took:

The graph will be above the $x$ axis when there are no real roots, such that $b^2-4ac<0$

So I got,

$$(m+7)^2 -4(m)(m+15)<0\Rightarrow m^2+14m+49-4m^2-60m<0\Rightarrow -3m^2-46m+49<0$$

Then I used the quadratic formula:

$$\frac { 46\pm \sqrt { (-46)^{ 2 }-4(-3)(49) }  }{ 2(-3) } \Rightarrow \frac { 46\pm \sqrt { 2704 }  }{ -6 } \Rightarrow \frac { 46\pm 52 }{ -6 } $$

I used the two solutions to turn this into:

$$(m-1)(m+\frac { 49 }{ 3 } )<0$$

So, in order to be negative the solutions must come from:

$$(m-1)<0,\quad (m+\frac { 49 }{ 3 } )<0,\quad (m-1)>0,\quad (m+\frac { 49 }{ 3 } )>0$$

However, the given solution $(1,\infty )$ makes no sense given the solutions I came up with. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That second inequality should be:
$$m^2 + 14m + 49 - 4m^2 - 60m < 0.$$

However, the third inequality turns out to be just fine.  =)

Comment: Note that $-3m^2-46m+49\lt 0\iff \color{red}{-}(m-1)(3m+49)\lt 0$.

Comment: $(m-1)(m+\frac {49}{3})=m^2+\frac {46}{3}m-\frac {49}{3}$ which by your previous inequality is meant to be positive, not negative.

Comment: @mathlove How is my application of the quadratic formula wrong then?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: $(m-1)(m+\frac{49}{3})\lt 0$ is wrong. It should be $(m-1)(m+\frac{49}{3})\color{red}{\gt} 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where you are making a mistake:  The condition
$$-3m^2-46m+49<0$$
is not equivalent to the condition
$$(m-1)(m+\frac{49}{3})<0$$
even though you have correctly found the zeroes of the first polynomial.  You can check that they are not the same by multiplying out $(m-1)(m+\frac{49}{3})$ and seeing that it does not give you $-3m^2-46m+49$.

What went wrong?  Simple:  You're missing a factor of $-3$.  The condition you *want* is
$$-3(m-1)(m+\frac{49}{3})<0$$

But there is a simpler way to finish this that does not require a correct factorization.  Remember that the graph of $y=-3m^2-46m+49$ is a downward-pointing parabola.  Since it crosses the $x$-axis at two points, that parabola must take on positive values between the zeroes, and negative values everywhere else.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! This really broke it down for me. I now realize that I should have multiplied both sides of the equation prior to applying the quadratic formula and flipped the sign while at it. That would have made everything much simpler for me and no mistake in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1:  $-3m^2 - 46m + 49 = -(3m^2 + 46m - 49)$.

Hint #2:  Multiplying both sides of an inequality by a negative number reverses the direction of the inequality.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand, but how is $m>1$ the solution here?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer, well you have $(m - 1)(m + 49/3) > 0$.  So either 
$$\{m > 1\} \land \{m > -49/3\} \Longleftrightarrow m > 1,$$
or
$$\{m < 1\} \land \{m < -49/3\} \Longleftrightarrow m < -49/3.$$

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of the right-hand side must be negative, that's right.

Now the discriminant is
$$
(m+7)^2-4m(m+15)=m^2+14m+49-3m^2-60m=-3m^2-46m+49
$$
and the inequality is
$$
-3m^2-46m+49<0
$$
that is,
$$
3m^2+46m-49>0
$$
The factorization is good:
$$
3(m-1)\left(m+\frac{49}{3}\right)>0
$$
which is satisfied when both factors are positive or both are negative, so
$$
m<-\frac{49}{3}\qquad\text{or}\qquad m>1
$$
However, what shape does the parabola have when $m<0$?

Comment: When $m<0$, the parabola has a downward opening; however, I want the graph to be above the $x$ axis, so $m<-\frac { 49 }{ 3 } $ is not part of the solution. Right?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer Yes, right.